# CSS Laravel modification issue

Tags: css, laravel

I downloaded a premake template of a ecommerce platform that contains css js views and such to apply to my Laravel framework project. It looked very nice but I would like to make some changes, for example color of the background. However once I tried to modified any part of the css file and then undo the modification, the website views gone really bad. the changes were undone but some of the effects seems no longer working after I made such modification, any explanation or solution for me to undo my modification?

I used MarkUps-dailyShop. Modified style.css lets say delete the below code in it

```
#aa-header {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

even though i undo such change, the homepage was of some sliding bar and dropdown menu before but now all these effects just gone and left with just words and colors.

I use Laravel 5.2

I place css and js script in the layouts.app as shown below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
        <title>Soyegg</title>
        
        <!-- Font awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-XdYbMnZ/QjLh6iI4ogqCTaIjrFk87ip+ekIjefZch0Y+PvJ8CDYtEs1ipDmPorQ+" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="{{public_path('css/bootstrap.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">   
        <!-- SmartMenus jQuery Bootstrap Addon CSS -->
        <link href="{{public_path('css/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Product view slider -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{public_path('css/jquery.simpleLens.css')}}">    
        <!-- slick slider -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{public_path('css/slick.css')}}">
        <!-- price picker slider -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{public_path('css/nouislider.css')}}">
        <!-- Theme color -->
        <link id="switcher" href="{{public_path('css/theme-color/default-theme.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- <link id="switcher" href="css/theme-color/bridge-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
        <!-- Top Slider CSS -->
        <link href="{{public_path('css/sequence-theme.modern-slide-in.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    
        <!-- Main style sheet -->
        <link href="{{public_path('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">    
    
        <!-- Google Font -->
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!-- datepicker -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <!-- datepicker end -->
        
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

<!-- contents-->


@include('layouts.navbar')

@yield('content')

@include('layouts.footer')

    <!-- jquery-2.2.4.min.js -->
    <script src="{{ public_path('/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap.min.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    {{-- <script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
    <script src="js/jquery.smartmenus.js"></script>
    <!-- SmartMenus jQuery Bootstrap Addon -->
    <script src="js/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.js"></script>  
    <!-- To Slider JS -->
    <script src="js/sequence.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sequence-theme.modern-slide-in.js"></script>  
    <!-- Product view slider -->
    <script src="js/jquery.simpleGallery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.simpleLens.js"></script>
    <!-- slick slider -->
    <script src="js/slick.js"></script>
    <!-- Price picker slider -->
    <script src="js/nouislider.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom js -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script> 

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need to know: Which template you downloaded, which files you modified exactly, does it use gulp ? did you run gulp ? What laravel version are you using, What have you already tried, give examples on code changes...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, my post edited as above

Comment: How is your laravel setup? The template seems to be bootstrap specific, not laravel specific. Where did you place your views, css etc. how do you load it?

Comment: thanks for your questions again! the codes are updated above. i am new to this so please let me know about the problem and things to improve! thanks!

Comment: Still pretty tough to tell where the problem is. I'm not quite sure why you require half of you scripts using public_path helper method and the other half using absolute routes. Do you have you application somewhere hosted so t hat we could take a look inside the actual loading of the scripts?

Comment: Where does your body start? Do you use any yields? where does your actual page content come from?

Comment: no im sorry im doing it on my local pc. thats because some of them were given by the template so I didn't quite modified them.

Comment: yes I did yield content at the end.

Comment: As said it's pretty hard to tell where the problem is - since the setup somehow seems to be broken. I can only give you some hints since I cannot see anything critical to be wrong
- Open Developer Tools ( F12 in chrome ) and try watch out for errors, some scripts might not be loaded
- Ensure your custom javascript and css does not override the theme stuff
- Try to load a minimal setup within the content and ensure everything is working
- Remove every css / js that is not needed for the landing page, add it later after you found the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried F12 but there are no errors at all. So I think I might have to work my way out of it.

Comment: Since it's a bootstrap theme you could also try to work without laravel in the beginning. First make changes to the theme without including a backend. Test it locally etc. and then put it into laravel. Maybe you will find the problem

Answer (score 0):

I just found where the problem is. It worked again after I change `public_path('css/style.css')` to `url('css/style.css')`
Is Laravel not supposed to read css by local directory?